# How to get special counts

Tags: mysql

Is following possible to get special counts?

```
ItemId | Colors
10     |  red
10     |  red
10     |  blue
20     |  red
20     |  blue
20     |  green
```

I need

```
Colors | Count
red    | 2  (not 3)
blue   | 2
green  | 1
```

If the color of the same ItemId occurs more than once, count only one

Comment: I don't know what "special counts" means. Do you mean you want to count all occurrences of (ItemID, Colors), rather than just Colors?

Comment: Yes, look my example

Comment: Is there any rule such that `red` is not counted as 3?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT Colors, COUNT(DISTINCT ItemId, Colors) `Count`
FROM test
GROUP BY Colors;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0604b5483e10dda1f97ccce1d7aa4cd6)

Comment: Just to observe that `count` isn't (presently) reserved, so the backticks are unnecessary

Comment: And I don't really understand what colors is doing in the count

Comment: @Strawberry I always quote keywords (function name in this particular case). It's a habit of mine... *I don't really understand what colors is doing in the count* I count the amount of unique `(ItemId, Colors)` pairs.

Answer (score -1):

This query will give you the required output:

```
select count(distinct itemid),color from item group by color;
```

Comment: I had tried count with distinct (big query with joins and subqueries) but only ever got count 1 but now it works.
Thank you very much!